# How to configure initial setup of cPanel nameservers?

Tags: nameserver

I'm setting up my first cPanel server on centos and I'm a bit of a newb.

Its asked me to enter in nameserver addresses ie ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com so I can then delegate my domains to it. I'm wondering though, when the domain I will be using is not currently delegated to this box, how it knows to go here?

If I go into my domain, say domain.com and it is delegated elsewhere, and I then tell it to go to ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com the registrar obviously won't know where to point it. My registrar also won't allow me to just enter the IP addresses I have.

What don't I understand?

In a standard VPS environment, would I delegate my primary domain (the one I plan on using for nameservers) to the hosting companies nameservers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. What that setting does is set up the nameservers so that when you do eventually point a domain to that address it all works.

So what you need to do is fill in the fields telling you what you want to set the nameservers to then point your domain to those nameservers (making sure to actually register these nameservers with your domain registrar).